# Use relationships without an extra model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 tables, `stores` and `employees`. The `employees` table is **not** persons, but just an estimate of the employees in a given store.

```
store
id | name  | fk_employees
 1 | Lewis | 2

employees
id | employees_amount
 1 | 1-5
 2 | 6-10
```

I could create an `EmployeeCount` model to define the relationship.

```
Store extends Eloquent {
    public function employees() {
        return $this->belongsTo('EmployeeCount');
    }
}

EmployeeCount extends Eloquent {
}
```

However, it looks cluttered to me having to create an empty class.

Can I do this in a smarter way?

Comment: You can't setup relationship without the other model. Can you do it in a smarter way? Probably yes, but it's hard to tell what is that you want to achieve with that.

Comment: Why not make employees_amount a field of store table? Isn't it much easier?